# Morning Netila without water

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, morning-day

So this morning I didn’t have water available to use when I woke up for Netilat Yadayim? What should I have done? Also when I did get water available again, say past chatzos, should I have made netila then with a beracha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Shulchan Aruch OC 4:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.22?with=Eliyah%20Rabbah&lang=bi) says that wiping your whole hand on a rough surface that can clean, is acceptable for prayer and learning, but not to remove Ruach Ra.

> אם אין לו מים יקנח ידיו בצרור או בעפר או בכל מידי דמנקי **ויברך על נקיות ידים** ויועיל לתפלה אבל לא להעביר רוח רעה שעליהן:

> If one has no water, one may wipe one's hands in a lump of earth or dust or any cleansing agent and recite a blessing on the cleanliness of hands, and this permits him to pray but does not remove the evil spirit from them

The [Elya Rabba](https://www.sefaria.org/Eliyah_Rabbah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4.15?lang=bi) discusses a machlokes if wiping 3 times counts as washing and removes Ruach Ra as well. Presumably, when the person comes to water they should wash again just in case.

The MB in [4:55](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.4.55?lang=bi) and [7:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.7.3?lang=bi) says that a bracha is only said for shachris prayers. So if the water was only gotten after prayers, there would no longer be a bracha. There are some who say a bracha should be said by mincha and maariv as well (Maaseh Rav number 3)

Comment: Would you wash with a beracha or no? Is there even a latest time to say netilat yadayim or like if someone somehow wakes up at 2 pm they can still wash and say a beracha?

Comment: I didn’t realize that was part of the question. I edited in the relevant answers